# get the width from own printf function

Tags: c, printf

I am making my own printf function. But, I am having trouble in getting the width from the va_arg if there is more that 2 digit number. For example at the code below, the width I get back is `23`instead of `123`. How can I get the actual width regardless of how many of the digit present in the width? Is there any other method instead of using pointer *s?

```
    char const *s = "%123s, hello";
    int i = 0;
    int width;
    
    while (s[i])
    {
        if(isdigit(s[i]) && isdigit(s[i + 1]))
            width = atoi(&s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", width);
    return 0;

//output = 23
```

Comment: Put the `printf` inside the `if` statement after the `atoi` call. You'll see `123` and `23` because `atoi` is called twice. When the `printf` is after the loop, you only see the results from the second `atoi` call.

Comment: Yes. How do I get the actual width which is 123 only.

Comment: You should search the string for a `%`, then check if the next character is a digit, and if it is you should use `strtol` to get the number. `strtol` has an `endptr` parameter that indicates where the number ended, and hence where the code should continue scanning the format string.

Comment: Ya, i already done the part for %.  Just having issue with getting width. And I am not suppose to use external function like ``strtol`` or ``for `` loop in this project.

Comment: @ShawnTeh Rather than add additional limitations sprinkled in various comments,  add _all_ your limitations to the post - best with the initial post.  Since you already have good answers, just live with the fact that you may have to do some adjustments to account for your late requirements.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could just break out of the loop when you've found the first digit in `123` to prevent calling `atoi` a second time for `23`.

```
int width = 0;
int i = 0;
while(s[i]) {
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) {
        width = atoi(s+i);
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
printf("%d\n", width);
```

Comment: Is there any other method beside using the break and the for loop as I need to return my width to be used in another function . I am also not allow to use for loop.

Comment: @ShawnTeh You can return the width after the loop, that is, after you've broken out from it - or return directly in the loop if the width is all you need. Use a `while` loop instead if you're not allowed to use `for` loops. Updated the answer

Comment: Inside the while loop, I have other ``if`` statement to check for other ``flag`` like ``- 0.*``. If I use the break, then other checking will be ignored. Is there any other method?

Comment: @ShawnTeh I think you need to update the question to put the other things you have in the loop there too. Otherwise, I would only be guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the length regardless of how many digits it is.  That is much easier to do with `strtol` (which returns the character after the number) rather than `atoi`.  Something like

```
    while (s[i])
    {
        if(isdigit(s[i])) {
            char *end;
            width = strtol(&s[i], &end, 10);
            i = end - s;
        } else {
            // do something else with the format character
            i++;
        }
    }
```

If you can't use the libary strtol, write it yourself; it is trivial:

```
long my_strtol(char *p, char **end) {
    // hardcoded base 10 and positive
    long rv = 0;
    while (isdigit(*p)) {
        rv = rv * 10 + *p - '0';
        ++p; }
    *end = p;
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I am not allow to use strltol in this project unless i write my own strlol funtion.

Comment: May I know what is this code for ```i = end - s;```

Comment: It sets `i` to the index of the character after then number in the format string `s`

Answer (score 2):

OP's code repeatedly attempts `atoi()` in the `while` loop. Only one conversion is needed.

Yet since `"%s"` may have *flags* like `'0'`, `'+'`, `'-'`, `' '`, which `atoi()` consumes, better to process with alternate code.

```
char const *s = "%123s, hello";

char *flag = s;
while (*s && strchr("-+ #0", *s)) {
  s++;
}
char *last_flag = s;

// Determine the minimum width
int width = 0;
while (isdigit(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
  width = width * 10 + (*s - '0');
  s++;
}

// Determine the precision
int precision = DEFAULT;
if (*s == '.') { 
  s++;
  precision = 0;
  while (isdigit(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
    precision = precision * 10 + (*s - '0');
    s++;
  }
}

// Missing step, look for modifiers h,hh,l,ll,j,z,t,L

printf("f: %.*s\n", (int)(last_flag - flag), flag);
printf("w: %d\n", width);
printf("p: %d\n", precision);
printf("Rest of format: <%s>\n", s);
```

---

More pedantic code would watch for overflow in `width * 10 + (*s - '0')`.

Example, cap the width to `INT_MAX`.

```
while (isdigit(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
  if (width >= INT_MAX/10 && (width > INT_MAX/10 || (*s-'0') > INT_MAX%10)) {
    width = INT_MAX;
  } else {
    width = width * 10 + (*s - '0');
  }
  s++;
}
```

Comment: ```width * 10 + (*s - '0')``` could cause overflow during unit testing. Where do you define the DEFAULT?

Comment: @ShawnTeh As the precision should never be negative, perhaps use -1.  The default precision has different meaning depending on the spacifiers like `s`, `d`, `f`.

Comment: @ShawnTeh Yes `width * 10 + (*s - '0')`  could overflow. It is UB with `printf()`. Add code as needed to do what you want.  Before the computation, test for `if (width >= INT_MAX/10 && (width > INT_MAX/10 || (*s-'0') > INT_MAX%10)) Handle_overflow();`.